# Python flask - using variable value in a nested loop

Tags: python, flask

I have 2 lists created fetching some json endpoints. One of them `entities` has a list of items and the id of their authors (they can have many of them). The second has the list of the authors, their id and their names: `authors`. I want to display the author name in the loop. My code

```
{% for entity in entities %}
  {{entity['title']}}
  {% for entityauthor in entity['authors'] %}
  {{entityauthor['id_author'}} {# this displays the author id #} 
    {# now I would like to loop into the athors list and test if the id is the same as entityauthor['id_author'] #}
    {% for author in authors if author['id_author'] is entityauthor['id_author'] %} {# this does not work because "entityauthor" is no more defined in the loop #}
    {{author['name']}}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% for version in entity['versions'] %}
    <p class="texttranslated">{{version['text_translated']}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is it possible to do something like this or I should restructure the data in the python app?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using `{%set variable=something%}`. Here is the code:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
  {{entity['title']}}
{% for author in entity['authors'] %}
{%set idauthor = author['id_author']%}
{{idauthor}}
  {% for author in authors %}
    {% if author['id_author']==idauthor %}
                            <span>{%for name in author.versions %}</span>
                                  {{name['name']}}  
                                  {% endfor %}
    {%endif%}
  {% endfor %}          
{% endfor %}

  {% for version in entity['versions'] %}
    <p class="texttranslated">{{version['text_translated']}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```